# Where to download 3.5.17?

Tags: ee2, ee3, upgrade, ee2-upgrades

We inherited an EE site, and are working with the client to upgrade from v2.10.1 to the latest v5. We are working on the initial 2->3 upgrade and found some instructions [here](https://docs.expressionengine.com/v3/installation/upgrade_from_2.x.html).

Step 4, unfortunately, has a broken download link:

> Download the latest release of ExpressionEngine (either ExpressionEngine Core or the standard edition, whichever your site is currently running) and unzip the files to a folder on your computer.

I assume since these are dated instructions, when they say "latest release", they actually mean download v3.5.17.

Where else might we get the files needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is the right file https://github.com/ExpressionEngine/ExpressionEngine/releases/tag/3.5.17

If you're upgrading a site from an earlier EE version, remember to follow the instruction under the heading "If you're installing from the repository". You may already have an existing `system/user/config/config.php` file with variable assignations that may be relevant.

Comment: That looks to be it! Tagged releases are nice, you don't see that with every framework :)